# Jquery why I can't show object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

```
$(function () {     
    setTimeout(function() {
            var subcategory1 = $("body").find("#navCatLvl2 a");
            var OdjSubcategory1 = {};

            $(subcategory1).each(function(subcategory1,elem1) {

                    var num1 = subcategory1 + 1;
                    $(this).trigger('click');                               


                var ArrOdjSubcategory1 = {
                    "SubCategoryId1" : num1,
                    "Name" : $(this).attr('data-text')
                };

                OdjSubcategory1[num1] = ArrOdjSubcategory1;

            });
        console.log('OdjSubcategory1 = ' + OdjSubcategory1);
    }, 2000);
    console.log(OdjSubcategory1);
});
```

we get error:

> ReferenceError: `OdjSubcategory1` is not defined on line `console.log(OdjSubcategory1);`

Why i get it error if `console.log('OdjSubcategory1 = ' + OdjSubcategory1);` show `OdjSubcategory1 = [object Object]` ??

Comment: OdjSubcategory1 contains in other context. You need to closure this variable, something like this $(function () { var OdjSubcategory1 = {}; setTimeout(function() {....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `console.log` exists outside of the `setTimeout` scope. `OdjSubcategory1` no longer exists (it's out of scope).

See comments in code below:

```
$(function () {     
    setTimeout(function() {
            var subcategory1 = $("body").find("#navCatLvl2 a");
            var OdjSubcategory1 = {};

            $(subcategory1).each(function(subcategory1,elem1) {

                    var num1 = subcategory1 + 1;
                    $(this).trigger('click');                               


                var ArrOdjSubcategory1 = {
                    "SubCategoryId1" : num1,
                    "Name" : $(this).attr('data-text')
                };

                OdjSubcategory1[num1] = ArrOdjSubcategory1;

            });
        console.log('OdjSubcategory1 = ' + OdjSubcategory1);
    }, 2000); // The scope of everything declared within setTimeout ends here
    console.log(OdjSubcategory1);
});
```

Moving the `console.log` within the `setTimeout` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

the variable `OdjSubcategory1` is local.

try this:

```
$(function () {     
var OdjSubcategory1 = {};//<--- global now
setTimeout(function() {
        var subcategory1 = $("body").find("#navCatLvl2 a");
        $(subcategory1).each(function(subcategory1,elem1) {
            var num1 = subcategory1 + 1;
            $(this).trigger('click');  
            var ArrOdjSubcategory1 = {
                "SubCategoryId1" : num1,
                "Name" : $(this).attr('data-text')
            };
            OdjSubcategory1[num1] = ArrOdjSubcategory1;
        });
    console.log('OdjSubcategory1 = ' + OdjSubcategory1);
}, 2000);
console.log(OdjSubcategory1);
});
```